# My function keep refreshing

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, forms, submit

I have litte problem, why my page keeps refreshing after the data is being displayed. I use this code,

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" align="center" Onclick="hitung()" class="myButton" >
```

But it goes well if i change the `type="submit"` to `type="button"`

here my function `hitung()`

```js
function hitung(){

var e = (document.getElementById("ifin").value);
var a = (document.getElementById("Furniture").value);
var panjang =(document.getElementById("ipanjang").value);
var ht = 0.0;
var hf = 0.0;
var total = 0.0;

if (e == "hpl") {

    hf = 0.0;
   }
else if(e == "cat")
   {
    hf = 0.5;
}
else {
    hf = 0.0;
}
if (a == "kitchen"){
    ht = 1.7; 
}
else if (a == "meja"){
    ht = 2.3; 
}
else {
    ht = 0.0;
}
total = panjang*ht+hf;
document.getElementById("ototal").innerHTML ="Harga Total : Rp."+total.toFixed(2)+"0.000,00"+"<br>Sudah termasuk ongkir";
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Because inputs with type of "submit" will submit the form (if it is inside form with action), so basically, if you click on that submit button, it will go to the specified form action.

Comment: The question is incomplete , Please provide the full page code or content of hitung()

Comment: i've tried use `event.preventDefault()` but thats make my function not working

Answer (score 0):

Change hithung()  definition to :

```
   function hitung(e)
{
e.preventDefault();

// Body of function.

}
```

Comment: my result wont come out if i use that function

Comment: So , you need the submission of form?

Comment: yes, I want the results do not close when i use `type="submit"`

Comment: what is the result when adding e.preventDefault()?
Does this throw some error? check console.

Comment: its keep refreshing and my result dont come out

Answer (score 0):

if your `type="submit"` the whole page refreshes. To prevent this use `event.preventDefault()` inside teh `hitung` function

If this method is called, the default action of the event will not be triggered.
And for a submit type the default action of submitting is prevented.